# Qmake not working in a mounted smb dir

Tags: mount, samba, qt

I'm trying to use qmake in a samba mounted directory. Here is what I get

```
jj@deb32-6:~/smbShare$ qmake .
QFSFileEngine::currentPath: stat(".") failed
QFSFileEngine::currentPath: stat(".") failed
QFSFileEngine::currentPath: stat(".") failed
QFSFileEngine::currentPath: stat(".") failed
Cannot find file: ..
```

qmake works in any other directory.
I'm using debian 6.0.4 32-bits with kernel 2.6.32-5-686. 
My qmake is from Qt 4.7.4 built from sources.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I've found the solution : mount the directory using cifs rather than smbfs, and it works !
I added the following line to fstab :

```
//windows-computer/share    /home/jj/smbShare   cifs username=jj,password=***,perm,iocharset=utf8,uid=jj,gid=users,nounix,noserverino  0  0
```

To avoid putting your Windows password in the fstab file, you may use a credential file : http://anothersysadmin.wordpress.com/2007/12/17/howto-mount-samba-shares-in-fstab-using-a-credential-file/

Comment: Since you found the solution, you should accept your own answer so others know it is resolved. Perhaps also put an example in the answer of how you mounted with CIFS.

Comment: Sure, but I have to wait 2 days before I can do that :-).

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. For me, just doing a "mount -t cifs ..." from the command line was resulting in the same error when I did a qmake.  Adding the mount to fstab with the arguments you showed did the trick for me.